# What is wrong with my json whois API output?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have make a whois whmcs API to check domain availability that its output wont be parsed?
what is wrong?
sample output: http://adu.ir/7IaM9

> {"result":"success","status":"unavailable","whois":"+---%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AWhois+Server+Version+2.0%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ADomain+names+in+the+.com+and+.net+domains+can+now+be+registered%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Awith+many+different+competing+registrars.+Go+to+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.internic.net%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Afor+detailed+information.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AEXAMPLE.COM.AU%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AEXAMPLE.COM.FLORAMEIYUKWONG.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AEXAMPLE.COM.RAFAELYALUFF.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AEXAMPLE.COM.ZONE%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AEXAMPLE.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ATo+single+out+one+record%2C+look+it+up+with+%22xxx%22%2C+where+xxx+is+one+of+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Arecords+displayed+above.+If+the+records+are+the+same%2C+look+them+up%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Awith+%22%3Dxxx%22+to+receive+a+full+display+for+each+record.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3E%3E%3E+Last+update+of+whois+database%3A+Wed%2C+29+Mar+2017+09%3A50%3A20+GMT+%3C%3C%3C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AFor+more+information+on+Whois+status+codes%2C+please+visit+https%3A%2F%2Ficann.org%2Fepp%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ANOTICE%3A+The+expiration+date+displayed+in+this+record+is+the+date+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aregistrar%27s+sponsorship+of+the+domain+name+registration+in+the+registry+is%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Acurrently+set+to+expire.+This+date+does+not+necessarily+reflect+the+expiration%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adate+of+the+domain+name+registrant%27s+agreement+with+the+sponsoring%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aregistrar.++Users+may+consult+the+sponsoring+registrar%27s+Whois+database+to%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aview+the+registrar%27s+reported+date+of+expiration+for+this+registration.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ATERMS+OF+USE%3A+You+are+not+authorized+to+access+or+query+our+Whois%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adatabase+through+the+use+of+electronic+processes+that+are+high-volume+and%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aautomated+except+as+reasonably+necessary+to+register+domain+names+or%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Amodify+existing+registrations%3B+the+Data+in+VeriSign+Global+Registry%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AServices%27+%28%22VeriSign%22%29+Whois+database+is+provided+by+VeriSign+for%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ainformation+purposes+only%2C+and+to+assist+persons+in+obtaining+information%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aabout+or+related+to+a+domain+name+registration+record.+VeriSign+does+not%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aguarantee+its+accuracy.+By+submitting+a+Whois+query%2C+you+agree+to+abide%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aby+the+following+terms+of+use%3A+You+agree+that+you+may+use+this+Data+only%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Afor+lawful+purposes+and+that+under+no+circumstances+will+you+use+this+Data%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ato%3A+%281%29+allow%2C+enable%2C+or+otherwise+support+the+transmission+of+mass%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aunsolicited%2C+commercial+advertising+or+solicitations+via+e-mail%2C+telephone%2C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aor+facsimile%3B+or+%282%29+enable+high+volume%2C+automated%2C+electronic+processes%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Athat+apply+to+VeriSign+%28or+its+computer+systems%29.+The+compilation%2C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Arepackaging%2C+dissemination+or+other+use+of+this+Data+is+expressly%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aprohibited+without+the+prior+written+consent+of+VeriSign.+You+agree+not+to%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ause+electronic+processes+that+are+automated+and+high-volume+to+access+or%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aquery+the+Whois+database+except+as+reasonably+necessary+to+register%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adomain+names+or+modify+existing+registrations.+VeriSign+reserves+the+right%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ato+restrict+your+access+to+the+Whois+database+in+its+sole+discretion+to+ensure%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aoperational+stability.++VeriSign+may+restrict+or+terminate+your+access+to+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AWhois+database+for+failure+to+abide+by+these+terms+of+use.+VeriSign%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Areserves+the+right+to+modify+these+terms+at+any+time.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AThe+Registry+database+contains+ONLY+.COM%2C+.NET%2C+.EDU+domains+and%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ARegistrars.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A"}

I think it replacing "space" chars to "+" and it's not normal.
any help?

Comment: The data is URL encoded. You need to decode it

Comment: jsonlint.com : Valid JSON

Comment: I thought i decode that by echo json_encode($results);

Comment: What do you mean by "wont be parsed"? How did you generate that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem - it's simply that the data in the `whois` property is URL encoded. You can decode it by using `decodeURIComponent()`, like this:

```js
var response = {
  "result": "success",
  "status": "unavailable",
  "whois": "+---%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AWhois+Server+Version+2.0%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ADomain+names+in+the+.com+and+.net+domains+can+now+be+registered%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Awith+many+different+competing+registrars.+Go+to+http%3A%2F%2Fwww.internic.net%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Afor+detailed+information.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AAborting+search+50+records+found+.....%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.ACKNOWLEDGES.NON-FREE.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.AFRICANBATS.ORG%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.ANGRYPIRATES.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.AR%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.AU%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.BAISAD.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.BD%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.BEYONDWHOIS.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.BR%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.BUGBOUNTY.TEST.AT.CIPRI.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.CN%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.CO%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.DEADKNIFERECORDS.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.DGJTEST028-PP-QM-STG.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.DO%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.EG%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.FORSALE%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.HACKED.BY.JAPTRON.ES%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.HANNAHJESSICA.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.HAS.LESS.FREE.PORN.IN.ITS.SEARCH.ENGINE.THAN.SECZY.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.HK%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.HOUDA.DO.YOU.WANT.TO.MARRY.ME.JEN.RE%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.IS.APPROVED.BY.NUMEA.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.LASERPIPE.COM.DOMAINPENDINGDELETE.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.LOLOLOLOLOL.SHTHEAD.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.MAIKO.BE%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.MX%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.MY%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.NS1.CHALESHGAR.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.NS2.CHALESHGAR.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.PE%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.PK%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SA%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SG%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SHQIPERIA.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SOUTHBEACHNEEDLEARTISTRY.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SPAMMING.IS.UNETHICAL.PLEASE.STOP.THEM.HUAXUEERBAN.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SPROSIUYANDEKSA.RU%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.SUCKS.FIND.CRACKZ.WITH.SEARCH.GULLI.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.TESTZZZZ.3000-RI.COM.DELETE-DNS.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.TR%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.TW%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.UA%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.UK%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.UY%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.VABDAYOFF.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.VN%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM.YUCEHOCA.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AGOOGLE.COM%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ATo+single+out+one+record%2C+look+it+up+with+%22xxx%22%2C+where+xxx+is+one+of+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Arecords+displayed+above.+If+the+records+are+the+same%2C+look+them+up%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Awith+%22%3Dxxx%22+to+receive+a+full+display+for+each+record.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3E%3E%3E+Last+update+of+whois+database%3A+Wed%2C+29+Mar+2017+09%3A49%3A20+GMT+%3C%3C%3C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AFor+more+information+on+Whois+status+codes%2C+please+visit+https%3A%2F%2Ficann.org%2Fepp%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ANOTICE%3A+The+expiration+date+displayed+in+this+record+is+the+date+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aregistrar%27s+sponsorship+of+the+domain+name+registration+in+the+registry+is%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Acurrently+set+to+expire.+This+date+does+not+necessarily+reflect+the+expiration%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adate+of+the+domain+name+registrant%27s+agreement+with+the+sponsoring%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aregistrar.++Users+may+consult+the+sponsoring+registrar%27s+Whois+database+to%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aview+the+registrar%27s+reported+date+of+expiration+for+this+registration.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ATERMS+OF+USE%3A+You+are+not+authorized+to+access+or+query+our+Whois%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adatabase+through+the+use+of+electronic+processes+that+are+high-volume+and%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aautomated+except+as+reasonably+necessary+to+register+domain+names+or%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Amodify+existing+registrations%3B+the+Data+in+VeriSign+Global+Registry%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AServices%27+%28%22VeriSign%22%29+Whois+database+is+provided+by+VeriSign+for%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ainformation+purposes+only%2C+and+to+assist+persons+in+obtaining+information%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aabout+or+related+to+a+domain+name+registration+record.+VeriSign+does+not%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aguarantee+its+accuracy.+By+submitting+a+Whois+query%2C+you+agree+to+abide%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aby+the+following+terms+of+use%3A+You+agree+that+you+may+use+this+Data+only%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Afor+lawful+purposes+and+that+under+no+circumstances+will+you+use+this+Data%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ato%3A+%281%29+allow%2C+enable%2C+or+otherwise+support+the+transmission+of+mass%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aunsolicited%2C+commercial+advertising+or+solicitations+via+e-mail%2C+telephone%2C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aor+facsimile%3B+or+%282%29+enable+high+volume%2C+automated%2C+electronic+processes%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Athat+apply+to+VeriSign+%28or+its+computer+systems%29.+The+compilation%2C%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Arepackaging%2C+dissemination+or+other+use+of+this+Data+is+expressly%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aprohibited+without+the+prior+written+consent+of+VeriSign.+You+agree+not+to%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ause+electronic+processes+that+are+automated+and+high-volume+to+access+or%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aquery+the+Whois+database+except+as+reasonably+necessary+to+register%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Adomain+names+or+modify+existing+registrations.+VeriSign+reserves+the+right%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Ato+restrict+your+access+to+the+Whois+database+in+its+sole+discretion+to+ensure%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Aoperational+stability.++VeriSign+may+restrict+or+terminate+your+access+to+the%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AWhois+database+for+failure+to+abide+by+these+terms+of+use.+VeriSign%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0Areserves+the+right+to+modify+these+terms+at+any+time.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0AThe+Registry+database+contains+ONLY+.COM%2C+.NET%2C+.EDU+domains+and%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0ARegistrars.%3Cbr+%2F%3E%0A"
}

console.log(decodeURIComponent(response.whois).replace(/\+/g, ' '));
```

Comment: Thank You for answer but I want to output be a valid json without "+" , ...

Comment: In which case you need to change the return value from the server - assuming you have access to it. JS is not able to affect that. I'd suggest starting a new question about it, including your PHP code.